# Permission denied on connecting to free amazon EC2 instance

Tags: ssh

I want to connect to my amazon ec2 instance, I tried following commands, but all of them failed due to Permission denied , what is wrong and how to deal with it? thanks

```
[root@myxinrui temp]#  ssh -i "amazon.pem" root@ec2-18-138-165-86.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
[root@myxinrui temp]#  ssh -i "amazon.pem" ec2-user@ec2-18-138-165-86.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
[root@myxinrui temp]#  ssh -i "amazon.pem" kenduffy@ec2-18-138-165-86.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
[root@myxinrui temp]#  ssh -i "amazon.pem" ubuntu@ec2-18-138-165-86.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com 
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
[root@myxinrui temp]#  ssh -i "amazon.pem" ec2-user@ec2-18-138-165-86.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
[root@myxinrui temp]#  ssh -v -i "amazon.pem" ec2-user@ec2-18-138-165-86.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-18-138-165-86.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com [18.138.165.86] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file amazon.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file amazon.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.8 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to ec2-18-138-165-86.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:22 as 'ec2-user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:7NSDHawO3BImuFDcrGvi+cBW/mmVPU1nEPOz6srFo5U
debug1: Host 'ec2-18-138-165-86.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,null>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:0)

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:0)

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: amazon.pem
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi
```

Comment: Where is the file "amazon.pem" stored?

Comment: @Kenster the directory where I run the commands

Comment: Well, according to the debug trace, ssh can't find the file.

Comment: @Kenster but indeed the "amazon.pem" is in the same directory where I run the commands

Comment: Perhaps you're misspelling the filename? Perhaps the actual file has a space or something at the end of its name?

Comment: @Kenster the filename is correct, and I havn't modified the file